# How to efficiently replace quotes (or wrapping symbols) in the part of the dynamic html string?

Tags: php, replace, conditional-statements

I have a html string like -

`...style="background-position: left top; background-image: url("http://localhost/abc/{DYNAMIC CONTENT}") etc...`

What would be fast and efficient way to replace double quotes inside `url("")` part with single ones **if there are double quotes after style="** I don't need to replace quotes everywhere, just in that certain place. Thank You.

Comment: It would be good to know how the `{DYNAMIC CONTENT}` gets inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex (match with enough context for less false positives):

```
$src = preg_replace(
           '#(style="[^"]+:\s*url)   [(]"   ([^"]+)   "[)]#x',
           "$1('$2')",
           $src
       );
```

Though that only replaces one double quotes `" "` pair per inline `style=`. So you might have to run it twice over your source if you expect multiple malformed attributes/url("..") expressions.

Comment: Well might be a right direction, but example doesn't work. Also I wasn't able to find explanation about : symbol in regexp. Thanks though, +1 for the answer.

Comment: Really not? I've tested it with your exact example HTML snippet. -- The `:` just represents a literal colon, because `url(` must be preceded by one. -- http://codepad.org/QdhemmBY as test.

Comment: Sorry, Mario, you were right, there was a typo on my side, I accept your answer.